# Apache not starting alongside Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

Have a development server with 2 static ips. Apache runs on one, Nginx on the other. Everything seems fine except after reboot. Nginx starts Apache doesn't. Can someone please tell me where to look outside log files for what the issue could be...or tell me the process on how to make this work..

Thanks in advance...

**12/19/2018**

Rebuilt the server using only Apache. When binding it to a single ip to one interface it still does not start after boot. When I unbind it, it boots fine. Doesn't seem to be a conflict with Nginx on the other ip, seems to do with the binding of Apache itself...still perplexed...

Answer (score 0):

I went to sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf

[image]

Changed Listen 80 to Listen 8080 and I was able to restart apache2 after that with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because default port for both nginx and apache is 80. So for example when nginx starts, the port will be in use, and apache can't access to that port.

in ypur httpd.conf of apache, find the line that says `Listen 80` and change that port to whatever you want. then restart apache.

If this is not the issue, then report results of these commands in your post plz:

```
$ systemctl status httpd    // or apache2 instead of httpd
$ systemctl status nginx
$ jourcanctl -xe
```

Comment: its Ubuntu 18.04 btw...changed the port to 8080...still not luck...pasting results below

Comment: won't let me past because the text is too long

Comment: the problem is that apache can't access the port on your server. `make_sock: could not bind to address 75.151.215.226:8080`.

Comment: I get that....I had tried the same thing you suggested before. Nginx works fine...